# Is there a way to include poppler files with a mac app developed using python

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, poppler, pdf2image

I'm developing a macOS app using python that has a step to convert pdf to image. [pdf2image](https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/) is being used, and it has a dependency on [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/).
I want the app such that it does not have any external dependencies. (Such as installation of homebrew and poppler using homebrew)

Wanted to know if there are portable binaries of poppler for macOS similar to the [windows binaries](https://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/).

I tried to copy the files from the installation folder from macOS, but some library paths cannot be changed. I'm using pyinstaller to create the app.

Is there a way to include the dependent poppler files in app or package?